# Send parameter to class, but the class is wraped with array

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have some class that is wrap with array caled `screenData`, and i want to pass `indexTheme` to each of these class.

```
  
  int indexTheme = 1;

  final screenData = [
    const homeTest(),
    const productPage(),
    const trading(),
    const inventoryPage(),
    const masterPage(),
    const financePage(),
  ];
```

i can simply just pass data like this, but in the future i want to change value of int.

```
    int indexTheme = 1;

    const homeTest(
       indexTheme = 1;
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to pass parameters

```
Void changeIndexTheme(int newIndexTheme){
    for(var classInstance in screenData){ //instead of var it's better to write your class name
        classInstance(
            indexTheme = newIndexTheme;
        );
    }
}
```

I think this way works if you didn't try it before, now you can call this function to change all values